# How to set a max and min value for an order quantity that initiates a toast object?

Tags: java, android, toast, android-toast

My application takes in customer name, the number of coffees being ordered and whether or not the customer wants whipped cream and/or chocolate on them. It provides a live update of the total price based on customer order and once the order is placed it will provide the customer with an order summary. The customer should not be able to order a negative number or more than 10 coffees. I have already created the quantity counter but need help executing the TOAST object.
Here is my MainActivity java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> selections = new ArrayList<String>();
    TextView order_summary;
    private Button _decrease;
    private Button _increase;
    private TextView _quantity;
    private static int _counter = 1;
    private String _stringVal;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        order_summary = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textOrder);
        order_summary.setEnabled(false);

        _decrease = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubtract);
        _increase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        _quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textQty);

        _decrease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("src", "Decreasing value...");
                _counter--;
                _stringVal = Integer.toString(_counter);
                _quantity.setText(_stringVal);
            }
        });

        _increase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("src", "Decreasing value...");
                _counter--;
                _stringVal = Integer.toString(_counter);
                _quantity.setText(_stringVal);
            }
        });

        _increase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("src", "Increasing value...");
                _counter++;
                _stringVal = Integer.toString(_counter);
                _quantity.setText(_stringVal);
            }
        });

    };

    // start Order class
    public class Order {
        // declare order variables
        private int quantity;
        private double price;
        private double total = quantity * price;
    }

    // declare price variables
    private double coffeePrice = 5.00;
    private double whippedPrice = 1.00;
    private double chocolatePrice = 1.00;

    // adds selected items to order summary
    public void selectItem (View v) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
            switch (v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.chkWhipped:
                    if(checked)
                    {selections.add("Whipped Cream");}
                else
                    {
                        selections.remove("whipped Cream");
                    }
                break;
                case R.id.chkChocolate:
                if(checked)
                {selections.add("Chocolate");}
                else
                {
                    selections.remove("Chocolate");
                }
                break;
            }
    }

    // display order summary
    public void finalSelection (View v) {
        String final_order = "";
            for(String Selections : selections){
                final_order = order_summary + Selections + "\n";
            }
        order_summary.setText(final_order);
            order_summary.setEnabled(true);
    }

    //display in long period of time
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You cannot order a negative number or more than 10 coffees",
    //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I have a TOAST script at the bottom commented out, not sure hot to implement it correctly.

Comment: that probably goes in `finalSelection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the check on the button press:

```
    _decrease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(_counter <= 0) {
                 Log.d("src", "Decreasing value...");
                 _counter--;
                 _stringVal = Integer.toString(_counter);
                 _quantity.setText(_stringVal);

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You cannot order a negative number or more than 10 coffees",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Same thing can be done on the _increase button.

Comment: So will this actually prevent the user from going above or below the limit or is this just meant to warn them? I would like to prevent the quantity from being outside of the 1-10 limit. @RobVoisey

Comment: Yes, it does prevent them, note that all of the code is in the if statement.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. @RobVoisey